# Salesforce devops Center Azure Devops Support

Tags: release, developer-productivity, devopscenter

In some demos of Salesforce Devops Center I saw info that there is upcoming support for integration with Azure Devops and other VCSs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otvLf2eYlrk

However can't see any info about that in winter '23 release notes.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_devops_center_new_features.htm&type=5&release=240&language=en_US

Is it expected to show up with the next release?

Answer (score 1):

Kris gave the correct answer, but here's some new information.

In [this blog entry](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/06/get-up-and-running-with-devops-center-today), Karen Fidelak, the Sr. Director of Product Management for DevOps Center, posted a link to a [public roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/forcedotcom/projects/4) on Github. At the time of writing, [an issue called "Azure git integration"](https://github.com/forcedotcom/devops-center-roadmap/issues/34) was in the "Researching" stage on the roadmap. The [related milestone](https://github.com/forcedotcom/devops-center-roadmap/milestone/5), labeled "1H24", did not have a due date, and showed 0% complete. But based on the milestone label, one can surmise that they are currently targeting the first half of 2024 for that feature.

For what it's worth, it looks like Bitbucket (1H23) and Gitlab (2H23) are both prioritized ahead of Azure for support.

Answer (score 0):

The [page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_devops_center_beta.htm&type=5&release=240) in the release notes above the one you linked explicitly states what is required to use it:

> Who: DevOps Center is available to all customers and can be enabled from the Setup menu. To use DevOps Center, add team members as users in the org in which DevOps Center is installed. **Users also require a GitHub account and access to their team’s GitHub repository**.

Github is all that's supported as of Winter '23.

> *Is it expected to show up with the next release?*

Even if there was a published expected release (which there isn't at this point), with safe harbor, there's no *guarantee*. What we know, as you noted in some demos you saw, is the plan/roadmap is to support more than just Github.